# when i try to register . Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')

Tags: typeerror

When I try to register. I get the following error message:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
```

- And when I tried

  ```
  toast.error(error.response?.data.message || "An error occurred");
  ```
- It gave me:

  ```
  xhr.js:247 
  POST https://localhost:8000/api/v2/user/create-user net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
  ```
- Following is the source code:

  ```
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const config = { headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"}};
  const newForm = new FormData();
  newForm.append("file", avatar);
  newForm.append("name", name);
  newForm.append("email", email);
  newForm.append("password", password);
  axios.post(`${server}/user/create-user`, newForm, config)
  .then((res) => {
    toast.success(res.data.message);
    setName("");
    setEmail("");
    setPassword("");
    setAvatar();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    toast.error(error.response.data.message);
  });
  };
  ```